# How to express a plural of the cardinalities of sets?

Tags: formal-grammar

I express variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ as "$x_i$'s".

Similarly, when I want to express sets $\mathcal{S}_1, \mathcal{S},2, \ldots$, I also use $\mathcal{S}_i$'s.

However, when I want to express the cardinalities of the sets, how to use??

1. $\lvert\mathcal{S}_i\rvert$s ?
2. $\lvert\mathcal{S}_i\rvert$'s ?

I thought at first to post this question on English question board, but because I want to hear the answer from mathematicians, I post here. If the topic is not right, let me know. I will delete it immediately.

Comment: Simply write the cardinalities of the sets $S_i$. In this digital world it is advisable to trade brevity for clarity.

Comment: I’ve usually seen no use of “ ‘s “ in any of the above situations, but instead sentences like “the $x_i$ are linearly independent over $R$”, or, “ all the $\mathcal{S}_i$ are subsets of $\mathcal{S}$.” So I’d just say “the cardinalities of the $\mathcal{S}_i$.”

Comment: @NicholasCamacho is the statement "$f$ is computed by the blah-blah algorithm with given $N_j$'s" also weird?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I’d generally just stay away from “ ‘s “. The context usually lets the reader know that there are multiple $N_j$ in consideration. Technically, I don’t know if saying “$N_j$’s “ is wrong. So you could say “ f is computed by the algorithm with given $N_j$” is fine if it’s clear from context that there are many. Or just say “...with a given collection of $N_j$“ to emphasize that there are many.